# Publish will succeed only when publishing on high priority in 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, publishing

When I publish a page under Normal publishing priority, It is getting stuck at "Waiting for publish".

But when I publish with High priority, its getting published successfully. It happens only with some publication targets.

I found that setting memory limit in COM+ properties and increasing the window size in deployer config may solve the issue. I wonder why this occurs with certain targets.

My MMc snap in is like below.

[image]

[image]

Can some one tell what could be the reason.

Comment: Are there perhaps Publish Transactions stuck in your queue at the normal priority (check the entire queue, not just from today)? Also can you share some detail on your configuration, do you have an outscaled publisher and if so does it contain filters on any one of the Publisher nodes?

Comment: @BartKoopman. Thanks for reply.  Some transactions published to other targets works well with normal priority. I just found that the issue occurs only when publishing pages from only one publication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Publisher can be configured to pick up items from publishing queue after filtering based on Priorities, Publications, Publication Targets and Hostname.

Could you pls. check your MMC Snap-in Settings->SDL Tridion CM->Queueing Settings->Publisher (rendering)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated my MMC Snap-in settings in questions. Can you check if they are configured correctly.

Comment: You can double click on the first row [Publisher (rendering)] and get to see the settings.

Comment: Can you check the screen shot I have posted again.

Comment: Priority value 6 corresponds to 'High'. Hence the publisher is configured to handle only High priority item. You may choose to remove the Filtering by unchecking 'Enabled'.

Comment: Thnak you so much. My issue is solved now.

Answer (score 2):

Publishing Priorities are of three types:

1. High
2. Normal
3. Low

When an item is published (not for schedule publish) with any priority

1. Item will show the status as "`Waiting for Publish`" on Publishing Queue
2. Publishing queue will move based on number of Renderer's and Deployer's as mentioned on `MMC Snap-In`
3. If Item is published as

   - **`High`**, queue will take this item as priority than other items & wait for current item to complete rendering and then this item starts rendering
   - **`Normal`**, queue will wait for other items (which are published as "High" and for "Normal", those are published prior to this item) to complete the rendering
   - **`Low`**, queue will wait till other items (which are published as "High" & "Normal". For "Low", those are published prior to this item) to complete the rendering

Other part is about "Publishing Targets", publishing targets are mapped to different servers. One or more servers will be mapped to different publishers (If there are).

Each publishing target represent that it publishes to different servers.

> In your case, item is published as "Normal". Prior to you, there might be couple of items are rendering in "Normal" or "High" priority.
>
> Now you need to check the publishing queue for past few days to identify "How many items are there on the Publishing Queue in Waiting state".
>
> If the unwanted items are lying on the publishing queue from so many days then you need to do a clean-up activity by deleting the un-wanted items from the queue.

Comment: Thanks. But for me this the items published under normal priority under certain publication is not getting published. They continuously show as waiting for publish.Can you help me about fixing the issue.

Comment: @Patan: I have mentioned in my answer that you need identify how many un-wanted items are lying on the publishing queue. After identifying, you need do a clean-up activity (That is, by deleting the items from publishing queue)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am just trying to remove the items that are waiting in Publishing queue.

Comment: I removed all waiting transactions. But the issue still persists. Would increasing the window size in deployer conf at delivery side help here.

Comment: @Patan: On filtering, priority is set as High (6). Due to that, only items which are published to High got published